# Redirect old search to new one and keep first param

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a website that actually has this URL when someone search anything

```
/search?searchword=KEYWORD&searchphrase=all
```

and i would like to redirect it to the new ones:

```
/newsearch?q=KEYWORD
```

basically, preserve the **KEYWORD** param and rewrite the URL

I've tried `RewriteRule ^search?searchword(.*)$ /newsearch?q=$1 [L,QSA]` but it doesn't work, nothing happens.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule doesn't work because you are using `RewriteRule` directive to test querystring. You need to match against `%{QUERY_STRING}` or `%{THE_REQUEST}` as mentioned in the answer by @RavinderSingh13.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^searchword=([^&]+)&searchphrase=.+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^search/?$ /newsearch?q=%1 [L,R]
```

Comment: I still have a problem with this. This query `/search?searchword=two%20words&searchphrase=all` is being redirected to `/newsearch?q=two%2520words` (please note the extra `%2520` instead of `%20`). Thanks.

Comment: I fixed it with `RewriteRule ^search/?$ /newsearch?q=%1 [NE,L,R]` (No Escape)

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, based on your shown samples only. You need to catch string after `searchword=` and before `&` into back reference(temp memory) to fetch it while doing rewriting url.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/search\?searchword=([^&]*)&searchphrase=all[^\s&]*\s [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/newsearch [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /newsearch?q=%1 [NC,L]
```

When I check this with `curl` command if this is rewriting correctly or not and it looks fine there.

```
curl -IL "http://localhost:80/search?searchword=KEYWORD&searchphrase=all"
Server: Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1g PHP/7.4.11
Location: http://localhost/newsearch?q=KEYWORD
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Comment: I've tried the new one, but Error 500 with : "Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error." in the Apache error.log :(

Comment: @ac_s_fer, could you please try my edit rules once and let me know, please make sure you clear cache of your browser before testing them, kindly do let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks, but same error :( It occurs only if I visit `search?searchword=keyword&searchphrase=all`but not if I visit `search?searchword=keyword'`if it helps. With this last one, no error but no redirection too. All caches cleared between several tries.

Comment: `curl -IL "https://localhost/search?searchword=KEYWORD&searchphrase=all"
HTTP/2 500`
versus
`curl -IL "https://localhost/search?searchword=KEYWORD"
HTTP/2 200`